# INET installation bug

Tags: omnet++, inet

I installed Omnet++4.4.1.I selected INET check box and click install.I got error 'Installing Project' has encountered a problem.

Cannot download archive from: http://omnetpp.org/download/contrib/models/inet-2.4.0-src.tgz

Comment: I turned off firewall in mylaptop.I am using broadband internet in my home.I tried the same steps again,but same problem message occured.Aditionally "Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://omnetpp.org/download/contrib/models/inet-2.4.0-src.tgz" also occured

Comment: That's the "forbidden" status code. So maybe your IP or your IP range is blocked from accessing the server. Don't know why though.

Comment: Did you try to download from the Github website? 
https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/releases

Answer (score 2):

I can download the provided URL.
If you cannot access it, maybe your provider or institution is blocking it?
You could try to use a proxy if you cannot download any of the INET versions form the INET website: https://inet.omnetpp.org/Download.html
Or, of course, download from Github: https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/releases